# How Do I only accept Numeric Digits in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm New to C# with Xamarin. Im using Visual Studio for Mac Preview to work on an iOS app.
When Making a basic calculator I can't figure out how to not accept answers that aren't a numeric digit. For example in my Text box if I put in a letter I want an error that says

> "Please enter a numeric digit".

I don't know why I'm getting an error but its not working.

When I run it and put in a number it just defaults to the else statement every time. Also with Letters. And when I put too many letters in it crashes.

```
    partial void AddButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        double number1 = 0.00;
        double answer = 0.00;
        double number2 = 0.00;

        int value;
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out value))
        {
            number1 = double.Parse(Number1TextBox.Text);
            number2 = double.Parse(Number2TextBox.Text);
            answer = number1 + number2;
            AnswerLabel.Text = "The answer is: " + answer.ToString();                             
        }
        else
        {

            InvalidLabel.Text = "Please enter a Numeric Digit";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it do the same with `int.TryParse`?

Comment: Side note: do you have sample of non-numeric digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is `string input = Console.ReadLine();`
Why are you expecting a correct value with that statement? That would be valid for a console program but you are running an iOS app.

It would make sense something like:

```
string input = YourTextInput.Text;
```

If you want to restrict the text input to a keyboard with numbers, use the following:

```
YourTextInput.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
```

And one more thing. If the answer should be a `double`, you should use `double.TryParse(input, out value)` instead of int.

What about this?

```
double number1 = 0.00;
double answer = 0.00;
double number2 = 0.00;

if (double.TryParse(Number1TextBox.Text, out number1)
    && double.TryParse(Number2TextBox.Text, out number2))
{
    answer = number1 + number2;
    AnswerLabel.Text = "The answer is: " + answer.ToString();                             
}
else
{
    InvalidLabel.Text = "Please enter a Numeric Digit";
}
```

You still need to validate the number entered, as the number pad allows to type more than one decimal point.

Comment: Oh so instead of the .text I have at the end of my number1 and number2 right? Do I even need all that if else stuff or can I just delete it all and put ...number1TextBox.KeyboardType=UIKeyboardType.NumberPad? Do I need the string part? If not I'll delete all if else crap. Thanks.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks. And to clarify where it says "InvalidLabel.Text" I change the ".Text" to ".KeyboardType....." right? Also where does the string input you mentioned earlier go?

Comment: The `KeyboadType` needs to be assigned only to the text field where the user inputs the number. A label cannot accept any input.

Comment: I posted what my code looks like now. If you could help me I would appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: alright this is getting Confusing on where to post my questions. Sorry. Now for some reason its working now like you said. When I input a letter or decimal it comes up with "Please enter a key". So thats working. Now I still can't figure out in Xamarin how to only accept a Numeric Keypad. No letters. If you could show me where to put the code for Xamarin I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: FYI numberPad is a keyboard type that isn't available on iPad. The machine will display the default keyboard instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend changing the TextBox so the keyboard which appears is numeric only.

```
<Entry Keyboard="Numeric" />
```

Check out this [Xamarin Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/choose-keyboard-for-entry/) for more info.

Comment: Can you show me where to go to add this entry keyboard numeric line? Do I just add it under partial void? If not where do I add this code? Thanks

Comment: I'd check out @xleon's answer as their answer is more detailed and touches on my point. Also, don't forget to accept a correct answer so users who find this post in the future will know what works :)